# SharePoint 2013 - Prevent Site Pages or Publishig Pages from showing in Search Results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

With SharePoint 2013, is there a way to tell SharePoint that I have **specific** site pages or specific publishing pages that I do not want to show on search result pages? Where would the settings for this be?

I'm using the search box snippet and search content snippet for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this two ways

1. Change the result query and add `-filename:pagename.aspx` - This will remove `pagename.aspx` from the results
2. Edit the Crawl Rules from CA -> Search Administration Page. Here you can add a rule which says to exclude the results from a Path, Or use a Regular Expression etc.

Comment: so adding the - mark infront of filename makes that happen?

Comment: Yes. The minus sign (-) will do the trick.